# Google Cloud Identity free user limit exceed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I have a Google Cloud Identity Free with one domain. As I know it's possible to create 50 user in it. I synced approx 30 users but I cannot create more. I've deleted some users but I still cannot create new ones. I've tried the sync from LDAP throug GCDS application and it said I've reached the user limit. Tried to upload a csv file. And at the end create a user on the admin interface. All of them were unsuccessful.

When I tried to create a user on the admin interface I've got an error message I reached the ONE user limit.

Currently I have 4 users. All of them can use the services only (GCP).

I really need more users. Anybody experienced the same or similar? The support only shows the help, which does not contains any relevant information about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also synching groups?

Please reach out to our billing team to increase the limit to 100 via:

https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7295541 (see link to form)

or use the general contact form:

https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

~ Luc

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've created a support ticket. Only one Group synced but I've synced Organization Units

Comment: So organization units and groups count as users? If our spend on other services like translate is high enough can we be bumped free to more than 100?